# Spring 4.1.6 - Load ".properties" and initialize a bean with that

Tags: java, spring, managed-bean, properties-file

I'm new with Spring MVC and I'm doing some tests. I was trying to find some answers about this issues, but most of them make references to Spring 3.11 and I'm using the last release: 4.1.6.

I want to load a ".properties" file when the application starts, and use the information in it to create a bean to access it in all the context of the app.

So far, I reach to load the file in the **servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
  ...
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:resources/Resources.properties" />
</beans:beans>
```

I think (not really sure) that I correctly declared the bean in the **root-context.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
  <bean id="Resources" class="ar.com.violenciaesmentir.blog.resources.ResourcesDB"/>
</beans>
```

And I also think I made the bean correctly, but I don't really know if the annotations are right:

```
package ar.com.violenciaesmentir.blog.resources;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ResourcesDB {
  @Value("DB.NAME")
  private String name;

  @Value("DB.TYPE")
  private String type;

  @Value("DB.USER")
  private String user;

  @Value("DB.PASS")
  private String pass;

  @Value("DB.DRIVER")
  private String driver;

  @Value("DB.URL")
  private String url;

  @Value("DB.MAXACTIVE")
  private String maxActive;

  @Value("DB.MAXIDLE")
  private String maxIdle;

  @Value("DB.MAXWAIT")
  private String maxWait;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public String getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
  }

  public String getPass() {
    return pass;
  }

  public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass = pass;
  }

  public String getDriver() {
    return driver;
  }

  public void setDriver(String driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
  }

  public String getUrl() {
    return url;
  }

  public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
  }

  public String getMaxActive() {
    return maxActive;
  }

  public void setMaxActive(String maxActive) {
    this.maxActive = maxActive;
  }

  public String getMaxIdle() {
    return maxIdle;
  }

  public void setMaxIdle(String maxIdle) {
    this.maxIdle = maxIdle;
  }

  public String getMaxWait() {
    return maxWait;
  }

  public void setMaxWait(String maxWait) {
    this.maxWait = maxWait;
  }
}
```

My ".properties" file:

```
DB.NAME = jdbc/Blog
DB.TYPE = javax.sql.DataSource
DB.USER = blog
DB.PASS = blog
DB.DRIVER = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
DB.URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
DB.MAXACTIVE = 20
DB.MAXIDLE = 5
DB.MAXWAIT = 10000
```

I think the reference is ok because it gave me troubles when starting the server, saying that it couldn't find the property for "name", but I was doing the annotation wrong and then I fixed.

What I want is to have that bean initialized and be avaible to have an attribute in the DB class like:

```
@ManagedAttribute
private ResourcesDB resources;
...
public void foo() {
  String dbName = resources.getName();
}
```

When I try it, **resources** is null. What I'm doing wrong?

-----**UPDATE**-----
Ok, I could solve the problem doing some try&fail with the answers given. First of all, I corrected the **@Value** like **("${DB.NAME}")** and added a value to the service annotation **@Service(value="Resources")**.

Then, the only change I got to do was in the **servlet-context.xml**. Instead of:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:resources/Resources.properties" />
```

I used:

```
<beans:bean id="configuracion" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <beans:property name="location" value="classpath:Resources.properties"/>
</beans:bean>
```

And used **@Autowire** instead of **@ManagedBean** to access the bean.

Comment: look for PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, and you should use "${db.user}"

Comment: You should look into Spring Boot and `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things flawed in your code.

1. Your `@Value` expressions are wrong
2. Your `<context:property-placeholder />` must be in the same context as the beans

When using `@Value` you have to use placeholders, by default `${property name}` you are just using a name. So update your annotations to reflect that. I.e. `@Value("${DB.NAME}`.

Next you have defined `<context:property-placeholder />` in the context loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` whereas your beans are loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`. The property placeholder bean is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and it will only operate on bean definitions loaded in the same context. Basically your bean definition are in the parent context and your placeholder in the child context.

To fix move `<context:property-placeholder />` to the same context where you bean is defined in.

Instead of `@ManagedAttribute` which is a JSF annotation use `@Autowired` or `@Inject`. And if you don't have a `<context:component-scan />` add a `<context:annotation-driven />`.

Comment: Sorry for take this much to answer, I was at work.
I did what you said, I defined the bean in the **servlet-context.xml**:  
  
`<beans:bean id="Resources" class="ar.com.violenciaesmentir.blog.resources.ResourcesDB"/>`
  
`<context:component-scan base-package="ar.com.violenciaesmentir" />`  
  
´<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:resources/Resources.properties" />`  
  
And write the values like **("${DB.NAME}")** and I have this exception:  
  
`nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'DB.NAME' in string value "${DB.NAME}"`

Answer (score 0):

Your [@Value](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) syntax is incorrect. It should be `@Value("${DB.NAME}")`.

You might also need to add this to your XML config:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:resources/Resources.properties" />
</bean>
```

The value on the location may vary, not sure on how you are structuring and building your artifacts.

Comment: I tried that in the first moment, and didn't work. Anyway, I'd try it again, but when I do:

    @ManagedAttribute
    private ResourcesDB resource;

Gives me compilation error:

    The annotation "@ManagedAttribute" is disallowed for this location

Comment: Hmmm i thought for sure that was the issue. Updated answer.

Comment: Your bean definition is the same as done with `<context:property-placeholder />`.

Comment: I update the question with the solution, part of it was this, so thank you very much.
Just a thing, in seems that in Spring 4.1.6 the definition of beans is "<beans:bean ... />". Thank you again.

Comment: @AndrésMarotta No it isn't that depends on what you add as a root namespace if that is something else as `spring-beans.xsd` then you need to prefix the `bean` element (and all other elements from that xsd) with the namespace you choose. This has nothing to do with spring but is simply how xml works.

Comment: Ok, I'm a little bit lots here. Since I don't have experience with Spring, I don't really know which things belongs to the framework and which don't.  
I know how to load parameters from a **.properties** file, what I want is that Spring manage that load so I don't have to.  
The thing is that it works, but not the way I want to. I have some problems with the context and where I have to declare beans. Right now, with this code updated, if I do @Autowired in an attribute of a controller class, it works. But when I want to do it in another bean, it doesn't.